# Points for which $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n |\sin(\pi k! x)|^{1/n}$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

For a sequence of positive continuous functions $(f_n)$, let's define $E$ as $\{x: (f_n(x))$ is bounded$ \}$. I need to find $E$ for the sequence of functions $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n |\sin(\pi k! x)|^{1/n}$.

I realize that $x \in \mathbb{Q} \implies x \in E$. Also I think that if $x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}$, we have $x \notin E$, however, I cannot prove it. I wanted to prove that there is some $\varepsilon$ such that $k!x$ doesn't lie completely in an $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood of $0$ in $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Z}$ for an irrational $x$, however, I cannot find a good way to approximate the $x$ with rational numbers with sufficiently small denominators. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Note that $f_n$ is defined by sum of $|\sin (\pi k! x)|^{1/n}$, not $|\sin (\pi k! x)|^{1/k}$. If $x$ is irrational, value of $|\sin (\pi k!x )|$ is nonzero for all $k$. So for arbitrary $m$, there exists sufficiently large $n$ such that $|f_n (x)| >= m$. Hence your expectation is correct.

Comment: Yep, I did indeed miss that it is $()^{1/n}$ and not $()^{1/k}$, and hence the claim follows, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $k_n$ be an increasing sequence of integers and let $\sigma < \frac{1}{\sqrt2}$.
Set $E = \{x; \overline {\lim}_{n \to \infty} |\sin(k_{n}x)| < \sigma \}$,
and let $\chi_{E}$ be characteristic function of $E$.

Claim $m(E)=0$.

To see this, note that on one hand
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \cos(2k_{n}x) dx$$ tends to $0$ because this is just a Fourier coefficient of integrable function.
At the same time since $\cos(2k_{n}x) = \frac { 1-2\sin^{2}k_nx}{2}$ one gets:
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \cos(2k_{n}x) dx = \frac{1}{2}m(E) - \int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \sin^{2}(k_{n}x)dx $$, so regrouping and taking upper limits:
$$\frac{1}{2}m(E) <= \overline {\lim}_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \cos(2k_{n}x) dx + \overline {\lim}_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\chi_{E} \sin^{2}(k_{n}x) dx $$
As remarked above the first term tends to $0$. 
The second one can be estimated by passing with upper limit inside the integral (Fatou's Lemma) and using definition of $E$, to get $<= \sigma^{2}m(E)$.
In words, for almost all $x$ upper limit of $|sink_nx|$ is bigger than $\sigma$.
Clearly it implies that $f_n$ are not bounded almost sure.